# How do I get at the params included in an RSpec response to examine it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, devise, rspec-rails

I am writing a controller spec (RSpec with Devise), and I know that the response returns the parameter I passed in to it (correctly so), because I see it in the output as this:

`...@params={"email" => "maddison_stokes@schumm.org", ...`

This is my controller spec:

```
  describe 'POST #create' do
    context 'when invited user IS an existing user' do
        before :each do
          @users =  [
            attributes_for(:user),
            attributes_for(:user),
            attributes_for(:user)
          ]
        end

        it 'correctly finds User record of invited user' do
          login_user
          post :create, { email: @users.first[:email] }
          expect(response.params[:email]).to include(@users.first[:email])
        end
     end
  end
```

When I run the test above, I get this error:

```
  1) Users::InvitationsController POST #create when invited user IS an existing user correctly finds User record of invited user
     Failure/Error: expect(response.params[:email]).to include(@users.first[:email])
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `params' for #<ActionController::TestResponse:0x007fa50d1ee6a0>
```

This is what the entire output of the response looks like:

https://gist.github.com/marcamillion/c2e3f4d0bdae05c2be1f

I tried to paste it here, but SO screamed at me for exceeding the 30,000 character limit. I would have truncated it, but didn't want to remove any info that may be necessary.

What I am trying to do is basically verify that the email in `params[:email]` contained in the `response` is the same email I passed to it. I know it is intuitively but I would like to do it programmatically.

Comment: Try `controller.params[:email]` instead of `response.params[:email]`

Comment: @Pavan that works. Thanks much! By the way, if you add that as an answer, I will accept it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> undefined method `params' for
>   ActionController::TestResponse:0x007fa50d1ee6a0

You should use `controller.params[:email]` instead of `response.params[:email]`

`params` are bound to the `controller` not `response`.